# Azure App registration permission scopes for SharePoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I created a new app registration in Azure Portal and added O365 SharePoint-Permissions.
I only allowed "Read user profile", what is the scope "User.Read.All". Then I  request a token and authenticate as a user, that is global SharePoint-Administrator.
The access token I get contains: "scp": "User.Read.All", what is exactly, what I expected.
But if I use this token to read files from site collections, this also works. I can perform search queries with the User.Read.All Scope- what shouldn't be possible, because I only delegated the "Read user profile"-Permission to the app, that uses the token.
Any proposals, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/list_get) or the [SharePoint API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)? I would suspect the latter (`SharePoint REST`) to be confused from the token and actually give you everything, because you are Adminsitrator. While the former (`MS Graph`) should behave properly and reject your token.

Comment: Yes, the latter. Mhh... so I should probably try with an non-admin account. Are you just guessing, that SharePoint missbehaves or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It's a guess. Try also using the MS Graph - it must behave properly. Guess is, cause your Sharepoint API now has an access token with user context. And it only looks that. It would not respect the scope, because it does not have concept of scopes. The Sharepoint REST only knows about users & their permissions within Sharepoint. Thus using the Sharepoint REST with a token for MS Graph (with Sharepoint is in the audience) you will always have the context of the user and not the scope. Which is not necceraly bady as user cannot grant morr scopes than they have. But it confusing with Admin

Comment: Okay well... Thanks. I guess it's like you say then :)